# Sort items in MySql with dots

Tags: php, mysql

How to sort id's widt dot's. I have this table:
`1, 1.2, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4, 5, 100, 101, 200 ...`

If we use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC` it will show:
`1, 100, 101, 1.2, 2, 200, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4, 5 ...`

But I need this:
`1, 1.2, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4 ,5, 100, 101, 200 ...`

Comment: Can you add the column type of `id` to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(id AS DECIMAL) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

other things you can do is make your column in database as FLOAT

and then you order your numbers as you do in your sql without CAST

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC
```

and it will work